# userform displayed by Application_quit in Outlook closes unexpectedly

Tags: vba, outlook, userform

I have a user form that is displayed in the `Application_Quit` sub of outlook.  It helps me to fill out a workbook each day.

My code runs perfectly when I run the macro normally, but when I actually close Outlook the macro displays the userform, but then it immediately closes.

I'm guessing there is no way around this?

EDIT:  Got a request for code - not much to see here, but here it is:

```
Private Sub Application_Quit()
    Dim Hours As New HoursWorked
    Hours.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Show us how you're displaying it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to display the form modally to prevent Outlook from closing until while the form is visible. What code do you use now?

Comment: ShowModal is set to true and I added the code showing the form above.  I'm actually wondering if showing the form modeless and having the vba loop until it is hidden in the background would solve the problem ...

Answer (score 0):

Add `vbModal` to your `Show()` statement. That will keep it alive and prevent Outlook from shutting it down.

```
Private Sub Application_Quit()
    Dim Hours As New HoursWorked
    Hours.Show vbModal
End Sub
```

Comment: No dice.  Properties of form already have it set to showmodal = true, but I did try this code and it did not solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

"By the time Quit fires almost everything in Outlook has already been
 released. There is no BeforeQuit event. The closest you can get to that
 would be to handle Explorer.Close on every open Explorer and check to see
 that Explorers.Count <= 1 in that event handler. If so then Outlook is about
 to close." Ken Slovak

http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/application_quit.3172885/